# KeyError in python 3.7

Tags: python, openpyxl, keyerror

The code gives an error saying KeyError in the end. But I believe the code is correct as written by the tutor.

```
import openpyxl as xl
from openpyxl.chart import BarChart, Reference

def process_workbook(filename):
    wb = xl.load_workbook(filename)
    sheet = wb['Sheet1']

    for row in range(2,sheet.max_row + 1):
        cell = sheet.cell(row, 3)
        corrected_price = cell.value * 0.9
        corrected_price_cell = sheet.cell(row,4)
        corrected_price_cell.value = corrected_price

    values = Reference(sheet,
              min_row = 2 ,
              max_row = sheet.max_row,
              min_col = 4,
              max_col = 4)

    chart = BarChart() #instance of BarChart class
    chart.add_data(values)
    sheet.add_chart(chart, 'e2')
    wb.save(filename)

filename = 'transactions.xlsx'
work = process_workbook(filename)
```

> C:\Users\bhargav\PycharmProjects\SelfLearning\venv\Scripts\python.exe
>   C:/Users/bhargav/PycharmProjects/SelfLearning/app.py
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:/Users/bhargav/PycharmProjects/SelfLearning/app.py", line 26, in
>   
>       work = process_workbook(filename)
>
> File "C:/Users/bhargav/PycharmProjects/SelfLearning/app.py", line 5,
>   in process_workbook
>       wb = xl.load_workbook(filename)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\bhargav\PycharmProjects\SelfLearning\venv\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py",
>   line 312, in load_workbook
>       reader.read()
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\bhargav\PycharmProjects\SelfLearning\venv\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py",
>   line 268, in read
>       self.read_manifest()
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\bhargav\PycharmProjects\SelfLearning\venv\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py",
>   line 136, in read_manifest
>       src = self.archive.read(ARC_CONTENT_TYPES)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\bhargav\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\zipfile.py",
>   line 1428, in read
>       with self.open(name, "r", pwd) as fp:
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\bhargav\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\zipfile.py",
>   line 1467, in open
>       zinfo = self.getinfo(name)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\bhargav\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\zipfile.py",
>   line 1395, in getinfo
>       'There is no item named %r in the archive' % name) KeyError: "There is no item named '[Content_Types].xml' in the archive"
>
> Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: Did you try a capital E

Comment: The "many error lines in between" is probably quite important to answering the question

Comment: Yes I tried using 'E' but did not work

Comment: do you have the right filename? and if you do, is the file in the same directory as your file?

Comment: maybe you should just look on the last error...

Comment: yes that is the right file name and it is in the right directory

Comment: It looks like the xlsx file is missing parts. Does it load okay in Excel or another spreadsheet program?

Comment: Yes it did. But after running the program it says "we have found some problem with the content"

Answer (score 0):

Check if the file 'transactions.xlsx' is in the same folder.

Comment: Yes it is in the same folder